# The class 'de.workshop.sales_tool.Model.Antwort' does not have a readable property 'text'. JSF

Tags: jsf

Hi i alwys get en error that The class '***.Model.Antwort' does not have a readable property 'text'.

here is the code:

the xhtml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding= "Utf-8"?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                template="templates/default.xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h1>Wizard</h1>
        <h:form>
                <ui:repeat value="#{wizardControler.fragen}" var="frage">
                    <h:outputText value="#{frage.text}"/>
                    <br/>
                    <ui:repeat value="#{frage.antworten}" var="antwort">
                        <h:outputText value="#{antwort.text}"/>
                        <br/>
                        <ui:repeat value="#{answer.teile}" var="teil">
                            <h:outputText value="#{teil.name}"/>
                            <br/>
                        </ui:repeat>
                    </ui:repeat>
                </ui:repeat>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

the Controler:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class WizardControler {

    private List<Frage> fragen;

    public void setFragen(List<Frage> fragen) {
        this.fragen = fragen;
    }



    public List<Frage> getFragen() {
        fragen = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            Connection con = DatabaseConector.getConnection();

            Statement stm = con.createStatement();

            String statement = "SELECT * FROM Fragen";

            ResultSet res = stm.executeQuery(statement);

            while(res.next()){
                String text = res.getString(2);
                int nr = res.getInt(1);
                Frage frage = new Frage(text,nr);
                fragen.add(frage);
            }


        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(WizardControler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return fragen;
    }

}
```

the other java classes:

Frage :

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Frage {

    private String text;
    private int nr;
    List<Antwort> antworten = new LinkedList<>();

    public Frage(String text,int nr) {
        this.text = text;
        this.nr = nr;
        try {
            Connection con = DatabaseConector.getConnection();

            Statement stm = con.createStatement();

            String statement = "SELECT * FROM Antworten WHERE FragenID = "+nr;

            ResultSet res = stm.executeQuery(statement);

            while(res.next()){
                Antwort antwort = new Antwort(res.getString(2),res.getInt(1));
                antworten.add(antwort);
            }


        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(WizardControler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }



}
```

Antwort :

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
class Antwort {


    private String text;
    private int nr;
    List<Teil> teile = new LinkedList<>();

    public Antwort(String text, int nr) {
        this.text = text;
        this.nr = nr;
        try {
            Connection con = DatabaseConector.getConnection();

            Statement stm = con.createStatement();

            String statement = "SELECT * FROM Teile WHERE TID = (SELECT TID FROM setztvoraus WHERE AntwortID = "+nr+")";

            ResultSet res = stm.executeQuery(statement);

            while(res.next()){
                Teil teil = new Teil(res.getInt(1),res.getString(2));
                teile.add(teil);
            }


        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(WizardControler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

the exact error is :

```
/wizard.xhtml @13,64 value="#{antwort.text}": The class 'de.workshop.sales_tool.Model.Antwort' does not have a readable property 'text'.
```

and here is the scope variables value of the wizardControler :

WizardControler(fragen=[Frage(text=Frage 1, nr=1, antworten=[Antwort(text=Antwort 1, nr=1, teile=[Teil(TID=1, name=Teil 1)]), Antwort(text=Atwort 2, nr=2, teile=[Teil(TID=1, name=Teil 1)])]), Frage(text=Frage 2, nr=2, antworten=[Antwort(text=Antwort 1, nr=5, teile=[Teil(TID=3, name=Teil 3)]), Antwort(text=Atwort 2, nr=6, teile=[Teil(TID=2, name=Teil 2)]), Antwort(text=Antwort 3, nr=7, teile=[Teil(TID=3, name=Teil 3)])]), Frage(text=Frage 3, nr=3, antworten=[Antwort(text=Atwort 2, nr=3, teile=[Teil(TID=2, name=Teil 2)]), Antwort(text=Antwort 1, nr=4, teile=[Teil(TID=1, name=Teil 1)])])])

EDIT1 :

Just tried and added the real getter for the text fild and made an brakpint there and after the error is displayed in the browser it gets triggert^^

Answer (score 0):

MAAN i hate problems like this -.- 5 hours and it was just a little "private" in front of the answer class -.-